# Map referencing class used by same class

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have a class that needs to keep a list of references of all its objects.
For example:

```
//A.cpp
class A {
    A() {}
    someMethod() {}
    someOtherMethod() { mapA[0]->someMethod(); }
}

//main.cpp
#include <map>

std::map<int, A*> mapA;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int count = 0;
    A* a = new A();
    mapA[count] = a;
    count++;
}
```

However, because `mapA` is only global to `main.cpp`, `A.cpp` can't reference it. I tried using `extern`, but because the `map` uses the same class `A`, I don't know where to put it.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Looks a bit like a flawed design. 1st of all why are you using a raw pointer stored in the map in 1st place. Would you mind to explain about your actual requirements and use case a bit more? Sounds a bit like a XY problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm writing a banking system with the basic `deposit()` and `withdraw()` methods. However I also have `transfer()` which transfers money between accounts of any bank. That's why I want the banks to keep track of all existing banks. Something like ABA.

Comment: What about having a superior parent container class for all the accounts, that offers an interface to do these `transfer()` operations? You probably should externalize that kind of business logic there. Also you shouldn't deal with raw pointers, have [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead.

Comment: How can I externalize this? I'm trying to think of it logically in that clients interact with the banks, giving them the amount to transfer, account to take the money, receiving bank, and receiving account. Then the banks would take care of the rest.

Comment: Well, `transfer()` should call `withdraw()` and `deposit()` at two participating accounts (in a safe non interruptible transaction)? `std::map` is too flat to manage that kind of business logic as mentioned.

Comment: Is that ideal? Seems like that'll go against encapsulation.

Comment: _"Seems like that'll go against encapsulation."_ How so? Exactly the opposite IMO. You may want to read about Martin Fowler's domain logic patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might register them in constructor, and make the static var in the class:

```
// a.hpp
class A {
public:
    A() { as.insert(this); }
    A(const A& rhs) { as.insert(this); }
    ~A() { as.erase(this); }
    static std::set<A*> as; // Declaration
};

// a.cpp
std::set<A*> A::as; // Definition
```

Comment: Hmm, that fixes the primary problem, but is this really the problem to solve?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I might imagine there are some valid cases to keep all instances in collection. It seems not be the OP's case...

Comment: Yeah, I think managing a plain container isn't what they'll need.

Comment: This did the trick, but I'll still read on @πάνταῥεῖ suggested design.